# differentiating density function

Tags: probability, density-function

If $X$ is a real-valued random variable with distribution $F$ and density $f$. We have that the distribution and density depend on the parameter $a$. Then since $f$ is density we have $\int f(x,a)dx=1$. Under what conditions is it true that $\int f_a(x,a) dx=0$? It makes intuitive sense but when I try say with the exponential distribution it doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_a$? Also $\int_b^b$ would be $0$.

Comment: derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $a$

Comment: Is this something you made up? Or is it standard? Because $f_a$ suggests a density of $a$ (to me).

Comment: $f_a$ is derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $a$. I get it that my notation is nonstandard

Comment: What mean w.r.t.??? Sry, Im not english speaker.

Comment: @Masacroso with respect to

Comment: The question is a little bit vague. The derivative is 0 at which point? or existence? If the derivative is 0 for all $a$ inside the parameter space, then the density itself is independent of the parameter $a$.